# When rabbis call each other “orphans” in an extended sense, just what is that extended sense?

Tags: talmud-gemara

The Gemara (Kesubos 106a) describes several large conventions at which people would gather to hear Torah discourses. When one of these conventions would disperse, students who remained behind were called “orphans,” obviously in some extended sense and without reference to actual orphans.

That makes some sense, I thought. When students leave school for vacation, actual orphans are probably sometimes put in a difficult position, with no families to go home to. So, these stragglers after a convention were responding like actual orphans to vacation.

Elsewhere (Kesubos 17b, Avodah Zarah 13b, Chullin 111b) the Gemara reports that rabbis would sometimes address one another with the word “orphan,” again in some extended sense. One rabbi might chide another for his unfamiliarity with the ordinary conduct of their rabbinical leaders: Did your mother rub oil on the heads of the rabbis during your wedding? Did your rebbe buy shoes or bread at the pagan festival? Would your rebbe eat two foods together, one dairy and the other prepared in meat dishes? What blessings would he say when eating fruit related to a meal in whatever way?

That makes some sense, I persisted in thinking. These are the sorts of things that you would expect someone to know if, instead of returning to his family, he remained in the company of his rabbis and observed their ordinary conduct. The examples never seem to be about things said in the course of Torah discussions (which an ordinary student would be expected to know), but rather about the way the rabbis lived. So, the term “orphan” is being used consistently in this one sense, for students who remained in the company of their rabbis at times when most students had gone to their own families; and the idea is that an orphan would be expected to know these things, and his ignorance is therefore the more striking.

But no, ArtScroll says, it’s all just the opposite. The stragglers were called “orphans” because they “were bereft of the vast numbers of students prevalent in bygone times.” Elsewhere, rabbis call each other “orphan” to express that they were “left out of the common practice,” or “orphaned of a proper teacher.” So obviously, although I thought that all uses of the word “orphan” consistently suggested someone expected to be more familiar with his rabbi’s habits, it turns out that the first uses said nothing about this at all, and the later uses said just the opposite, referring to someone who didn’t know much. And the pattern of examples deriving from personal life seems to escape all notice and to be a meaningless coincidence.

ArtScroll of course ascribes these explanations to standard commentaries, but in my experience in shopping this problem, absolutely everybody sees it the same way, with the one awkward exception in myself.

What does everybody like about this way of looking at things?

Comment: I think you're overthinking it. "Orphan" has a widespread connotation of someone abandoned, lacking support and guidance.